# No puedo levantar un reporte de jasperreport (error en la linea File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("")

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports

Estoy atravesando un inconveniente al intentar levantar un reporte diseñado en JasperReport.
A continuación el código contenido en el archivo JSP que contiene la llamada al reporte:

<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%@ page language="java" %>

<%@ include file="conexion.jsp" %>

<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %>

<%
try{

```
File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/clientes.jasper"));
        

Map parametros = new HashMap();


byte[] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros, conn);     
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream(); 
response.getOutputStream();
output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
output.flush();
output.close();
}
catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

%>

Luego, cuando ejecuto el jsp (de modo a levantar el reporte hecho en jasper) figura los siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Observación:** cuando se crea el archivo de reporte en Jasper ("clientes.jrxml", en sus propiedades por defecto aparece Language="Groovy". Entonces procedo a cambiar por Language="Java" y al compilar aparece un mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Observación 2:** tener en cuenta que en el Preview "no arrastra" ningún dato de la tabla consultada, es decir no permite previsualizar dicho informe. Creo que el origen de la imposibilidad de "levantar" el reporte a traves de JSP es este asunto (Language="groovy")

Comment: Hola Gustavo. Por favor, cambia las capturas de pantalla por el texto, tanto del código como de los mensajes de error. Si tu Jasper no valida no podrá funcionar, debes crear primero un Jasper válido. Otra cosa, ¿qué versión de Jasper Report estás usando? Lo de Groovy me suena a la versión antigua, que fue abandonada en 2015 (ya no es mantenida ni actualizada), si tienes esa versión considera pasar a una versión actualizada de JasperReport.

Comment: Padre Cedano muchas gracias por su comentario. Las herramientas que estoy utilizando: IDE: Apache Netbeans 12.1, Dependencia del reporteador: Jasperreports-6.16.0. Me resulta muy extraño, cuando procedo a crear un jrxml (archivo previo al jasper), al verificar su codigo XML veo que por defecto está la propiedad Language="groovy", entonces si me dirijo a Propiedades y cambio el valor del Language por "java" y ahi ocurre que ya no me permite compilar (en Report Problems Window me indica "The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files